# How to create custom shapes with pseudo classes in CSS3

Tags: css, css-shapes, pseudo-class

I am trying to create an element using Bootstrap that looks like this image
[image]

This is the screen shot of how far I have gone

[image]

I have never worked on pseudo classes and am finding it very difficult to get the exact shape. Please take a look at my code and help me figure it out. I have included only the second (thee one on the right side in the screenshot) clipboard's code here.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
     <div class="clip">
          <div class="circle"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="pad">          
          <div class="paper"></div>    
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clip, .circle{
    position: relative;
}

.clip::after, .clip::before, circle:after, .circle:before{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  z-index: 50;
}

.clip:before{
    top: 12.5px;
    left: 15%;
    width: 70%;
    border-bottom: solid 50px grey;
    border-left: solid 150px transparent;
    border-right: solid 150px transparent;

}

.clip:after{
  top: 60px;
  left: 15%;
  width: 70%;
  border-bottom: solid 55px grey;

  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;

  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.circle:before{
    top: 10px;
    left: 70%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-right: solid 150px yellow; 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a background image? You can scale that background to fit in all resolutions, and you don't need to make that shapes with pure CSS. Sometimes is not the best choice to make it with CSS.

Comment: Since images take longer to load in slower connections & the main thing in my page is this layout I didn't want to take that chance. I'll definitely consider that as an option. However, can you please suggest a CSS solution so that atleast I can get more knowledge

Comment: It's a hard task to make with CSS, so I can help you but I will lose so many time. However, the grey shape I'm not able right now to achieve that shape. I only can imagine that shape with a grey box with border radius and 45degrees rotated, inside a transparent box with an overflow hidden that cuts the borders and the bottom. But a pure CSS shape I can't make it with that. The other hard task is the diagonal gradient in the middle of the paper.

Comment: However, I can't reproduce your screenshot with your code. Share the complete example. See this fiddle with your current code: https://jsfiddle.net/esmrLzuv/

Comment: Me neither !!!! I have my entire code here but I don't know why it isn't working. I've even changed all my 'px' values to 'rem', still no luck. Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chandannadig/esmrLzuv/4/

Comment: As you can see, if we can't reproduce the correct behaviour that you have in your site, all of our editions will be in void. Please, try to reproduce the code in a fiddle to help me to help you ;)

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude: I want to make only the inner div '.list' scrollable. How can I do it ??

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude: Please checkout the latest update of my fiddle here:-  https://jsfiddle.net/chandannadig/3kjdo9rr/8/ . Everything is responsive except the Pseudo elements I have used and the Background image doesn't cover the entire length on mobile . I hope you should be able to help now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because there is no SVG tag, i'll go with pseudo & gradient :

```css
div {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  margin:60px 60px 80px;
  width:180px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:15px;
  background:white;
  box-shadow:/* draw inside part of border */0 0 0 20px #159E91, inset -1px -1px 1px;
}
div:before {/*to  draw outside part of  border with same radius inside/out */
  z-index:-1;
  border-radius:20px;
  content:'';
  border: 20px solid #159E91;
  position:absolute;
  top:-30px;
  left:-30px;
  right:-30px;
  bottom:-30px;
  box-shadow:0 -2px 2px rgba(30, 162, 149, 0.2), 0 0 2px white,  0 5px  5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
div:after {/* draw gradient underneath clipper */
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  border-radius: 0 15px 0 0;
  left:26px;
  width:152px;
  height:150px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(45deg, white 40%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 40% ),/* mask*/
    linear-gradient(-45deg, white  , transparent 70%),/* mask*/
    linear-gradient(to right   , rgba(0,0,0,0.25)  , rgba(0,0,0,0.15)),transparent ;
}
.clipper {/* hold clipper shape actually */
  display:block;
  width:128px;
  height:80px;
  margin: -52px auto 30px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.clipper b {/* show the clipper shape */
  border-radius:35px;
  position:absolute;
  height:150%;
  width:100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px gray;
  left:50%;
  top:-12px;
  transform-origin:0 0;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  overflow:hidden;
  }
.clipper b:before {/* draw the hoe and paint around it */
  content:'';
  display:block;
  border-radius:100%;
  height:29px;
  width:29px;
  margin:20px;  
  box-shadow:inset -1px -1px   1px gray, 0 0 0 100px  #3B3B3B, inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

/* to match fake picture's text */
.clipper ~ span {
  display:block;
  background:#353535;
  margin:10px 58px;
  padding:5px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.clipper ~ span:last-of-type {
  display:block;
  background:#353535;
  margin:10px 85px 10px 58px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="clipper"><b></b></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

but that's really much CSS for just a shape, where an image or an `SVG` would do fine for the design.

You can play with it here : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rLYYZx

Comment: I did some changes to the design. Now that I've got this far I wanna stick with CSS. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chandannadig/3kjdo9rr/10/  . Can you help me make the clipper responsive ?

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/ahe128/esmrLzuv/5/

i did something but this is realy hard work i will try complete this :)

```
.clip,
.circle {
  position: relative;
}

.clip::after,
.clip::before,
circle:after,
.circle:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  z-index: 50;
}

.clip:before {
  top: 1rem;
  left: 10%;
  width: 20%;
  border-bottom: solid 50px grey;
  border-left: solid 150px transparent;
  border-right: solid 150px transparent;
}

.clip:after {
  top: 4.65rem;
  left: 10%;
  right:10%;
  width: 82%;
  border-bottom: solid 4.3rem grey;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.8rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.8rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.4rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.4rem;
}

.circle:before {
  top: 0.78rem;
  height: 1px;
  width:1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 25px white;
  z-index:100;
  left:47%
}
```

Comment: Thanks ahe, please have a look at my answer and fiddle. For some reason, the code works only on my browsers, but not in the fiddle.

Comment: If you have trouble size, you can try the following solution
this is the bootstrap feature 
hidden-xs or hidden-sm exc.
for example you make two shape and one of them (for lg, sm md) class "col-md-12 hidden-xs" and the another one (for xs) class is "col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-lg hidden-..." 
I used it before on my proje and it is good solution for size problem 
sometimes bootstrap size setting isnt work our design and i think this solution is the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally.......I got it working (except the diagonal gradient). But it's not responsive yet. My aim is to keep each Clipboard's design intact and stack them one below the other in small screens. Can someone please point out where I'm missing it !!

Also, if there's a better way of doing it in **Pure CSS** then I'd love to see it.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chandannadig/esmrLzuv/7/

[image]

```
/*Clip*/
.clip, .circle{
    position: relative;
}

.clip::after, .clip::before, circle:after, .circle:before{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}

.clip:before{
    z-index: 50;
    top: 1rem;
    left: 6.958rem;
    width: 29rem;
    border-bottom: solid 4rem grey;
    border-left: solid 11.5rem transparent;
    border-right: solid 11.5rem transparent;

}

.clip:after{
  top: 4.7rem;
  left: 6.958rem;
  width: 29rem;
  z-index: 50;
  border-bottom: solid 4rem grey;

  border-top-left-radius: 0.8rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.8rem;

  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.circle{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 60;
    top: 0.4rem;
    left: 15.6rem;
    width: 12rem;
    height: 8rem;
    background: grey;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle::before{
    z-index: 60;
    top: 1rem;
    left: 4.2rem;
    width: 3.5rem;
    height: 3.5rem;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
/*End of Clip*/
```